# buscar valores repetidos y poner si es la primera , la segunda o la tercera vez que se repite

Tags: php, array

espero me puedan ayudar tengo un array en el cual guardo números que corresponden a una materia en especifico es decir son las id, pero necesito recorrer ese array e ir verificando que si se repite la materia quiere decir que es la segunda vez que esta en el array y así si sale una tercera ocasión es la tercera por ejemplo:
mi_array = [1,4,6,7,9,4,1,8,3,4]  recorrerlo e imprimir

```
1=primera
4=primera
6=primera
7=primera
4=segunda
1=segunda
8=primera
3=primera
4=tercera
```

espero sea entendible mi explicación y me puedan ayudar

```
$pdo = new DB();
    $no_mat = array();
    $query = $pdo->connect()->prepare('SELECT ID_ESTUDIANTE,ID_CARRERA,ID_MATERIA FROM `calificaciones` WHERE ID_ESTUDIANTE = ?');
    $query1 = $pdo->connect()->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT ID_ESTUDIANTE FROM `calificaciones`');
    $query2 = $pdo->connect()->prepare('UPDATE calificaciones SET `NO_MATRICULA` = ? WHERE ID_ESTUDIANTE = ? AND ID_MATERIA = ?');

    $query1->execute();
    foreach($query1 as $ids){
        $query->execute([$ids[0]]);
            foreach($query as $e){
            array_push($no_mat,$e[2]);//ESTE ARREGLO GUARDA EL ID DE LA MATERIA
        }
    //EL PROBLEMA ES QUE SI UNA MATERIA SE REPITE 3 VECES EN LA POSICION QUE ESTE ME SALE 3 Y NECESITO QUE EN LA PRIMERA SALGA 1 EN LA SEGUNDA 2 Y PUES CLARO EN LA TERCERA 3
        for($i=0;$i<count($no_mat);$i++){
            $cont=(count(array_keys($no_mat, $no_mat[$i])));
            if($cont>1 && $cont<3){
                $query2->execute([$cont,$ids[0],$no_mat[$i]]);
            }elseif($cont>2){
                $query2->execute([$cont,$ids[0],$no_mat[$i]]);
            }else{
                $query2->execute([1,$ids[0],$no_mat[$i]]);
            }   
        }
        unset($no_mat);
        $no_mat = array();
    }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Por favor, explicar mejor el problema, no se entiende. Explícalo fuera del código, no en comentarios al mismo, es difícil de leer y entender así. Gracias.

Comment: gracias y espero me puedas ayudar

Comment: Sigue sin entenderse, esto por ejemplo *recorrerlo e imprimir 1=primera 4=primera 6=primera 7=primera 4=segunda 1=segunda 8=primera 3=primera 4=tercera*  no tengo ni idea de lo que quieres decir ahí...

Comment: 'primera' quiere decir que es la primera vez que aparece en el array luego si vuelve a salir el mismo número 'segunda' y si sale una tercera vez pues se imprme a su lado 'tercera' como un acumulador en el ejemplo e 4 se repite tres veces en diferentes posiciones quiero ir acumulando las veces que se repite un numero dentro del array

Comment: Entendida esa parte. Ahora, sería bueno que expliques un poco el contexto, porque veo una serie de consultas y de manipulaciones de datos un poco recambolescas. Quizá si nos ayudas a entender mejor el contexto se pueda mejorar un poco todo el código.

Comment: ok necesito modificar una tabla de una base de datos que ya tiene miles de registros esta tabla en especifico es de estudiantes matriculados, le aumente un campo para poner el número de matrícula (es decir cuantas veces se ha matriculado en la misma materia) y así sacar un reporte de cuantos estudiantes tienen primera matricula, segunda y tercera y ya que no puedo modificar dato por dato lo hice con el código de arriba pero no me da el resultado esperado

Comment: Si es así, entonces es el diseño de la base de datos el que está mal. Intentar hacer que eso funcione va a ser muy complicado, mantenerlo mucho más y sacar información de esa estructura de datos más todavía. Deberías usar para tu caso dos tablas de entidades: `estudiante, materia` y una tabla asociativa `estudiante_materia` en la cual pondrías un registro por cada `estudiante` matriculado en alguna `materia`. Esa 3ª tabla podría tener un campo `fecha` por el cual sabrás cuándo fue la 1ª vez que el estudiante se matriculó en esa materia. Esta sería una forma coherente de resolver tu problema.

Comment: si lo se y tengo claro que la base de datos esta mal diseñada es mas ni tiene relaciones, pero no hay esa posibilidad ya que esa base era de un sistema que ya no se utiliza en mi instituto pero la información si tiene datos que se necesitan para los reportes que mencione, ya que me encargaron resolver entre otros este problema pero no logro ese objetivo aun solo e logrado con el código de arriba que me salga si se a matriculado 3 veces que me salga 3 pero me sale en las tres veces que se repite la materia el 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//LOGRE RESOLVER MI PROBLEMA CON ESTE CÓDIGO
//LO PUBLICO POR SI A ALGUIEN LE SIRVE O TIENE UN PROBLEMA SIMILAR
//DE TODAS FORMAS GRACIAS POR SUS COMENTARIOS

```
<?php
require('controladores/conect.php');
$pdo = new DB();
$no_mat = array();
$query = $pdo->connect()->prepare('SELECT ID_ESTUDIANTE,ID_CARRERA,ID_MATERIA FROM `calificaciones` WHERE ID_ESTUDIANTE = ?');
$query1 = $pdo->connect()->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT ID_ESTUDIANTE FROM `calificaciones`');
$query2 = $pdo->connect()->prepare('UPDATE calificaciones SET `NO_MATRICULA` = ? WHERE ID_ESTUDIANTE = ? AND ID_MATERIA = ? AND NUMERACION = ?');

$query3 = $pdo->connect()->prepare('UPDATE calificaciones SET `NUMERACION` = ? WHERE ID_ESTUDIANTE = ? AND ID_CAL = ?');


$ac=1;
$j=0;
$query1->execute();
foreach($query1 as $ids){

        $query->execute([$ids[0]]);
            foreach($query as $e){
                array_push($no_mat,$e[2]);
            }
        $unicos = array_unique($no_mat);

        foreach($unicos as $id){
            foreach($no_mat as $idss){
                if($id == $idss){
                    $query2->execute([$ac,$ids[0],$id,$j]);
                    $ac++;
                }
                $j++;
            }
            $j=0;
            $ac=1;
        }
    $j=0;
    $ac=1;

    unset($no_mat);
    $no_mat = array();
    $unicos = '';
}
?>
```